# How to schedule a cron job to backup a MySql database every week?

Tags: mysql, cron, database-backups

What is a command line I can use to back up a MySql database every single week into a file name with the date (so that it doesn't collide with previous backups)?

Also, is this a reasonable backup strategy?  My database is relatively small (a complete export is only 3.2 megs right now).  The churn rate is relatively low.  I need to be able to get the complete DB back if something goes wrong.  And it would be extra cool if there's a way that I could see the changes that occur across a time span.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Weekly backup with cron and mysqldump:**

Credit goes to @timdev answer (+1) for providing the command line.

**The cron syntax goes like this :**

```
* * * * * = [minute] [hour] [day of month] [month] [day of week]
```

However since you wanted weekly backups, you can specify the days on which to run the backup in the third start above (day of month), to simulate the weekly interval.

```
0 4 1,8,15,21,28 * * DATE=`date +%y-%m-%d`; mysqldump -u <dbuser> -p<dbpasswd> <dbname> | gzip > dbname-$DATE.sql.gz
```

This will run it at 4:00 AM on 1st, 8th, 15th, 21st, and 28th of each month.

Comment: +1 for correcting my answer.  Don't know why I thought he was asking for monthly when "weekly" is in the question subject...

Comment: It looks like 0 0 * * 0 is the better syntax to get this to be truly weekly.

Comment: yes, 0 for day of week means it will be backed up every sunday at midnight using that cron line

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
0 4 1 * * DATE=`date +%y-%m-%d`; mysqldump -u <dbuser> -p<dbpasswd> <dbname> | gzip > dbname-$DATE.sql.gz
```

Which will dump your database (and gzip it) on the first of each month at 4:00 AM.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [MySQL Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html)

> Replication enables data from one
>   MySQL database server (the master) to
>   be replicated to one or more MySQL
>   database servers (the slaves).
>   Replication is asynchronous - slaves
>   need not to connected permanently to
>   receive updates from the master. This
>   means that updates can occur over
>   long-distance connections and even
>   over temporary or intermittent
>   connections such as a dial-up service.

This way, if something goes wrong with your primary database (the master), the slave can serve as a ready-to-use replacement.

Comment: I am not concerned right now with the database itself being down.  I am concerned with data loss or inadvertent editing by users.

Comment: Totally agree. This was my think-out-of-the-box shot at "I need to be able to get the complete DB back if something goes wrong." I think replication does this and fast.